# what does enum DescriptorType DescriptorType :8; mean in C code?

Tags: c, struct, enumeration, bit-fields

This is part of the code. I can not understand what does

```
enum DescriptorType DescriptorType :8;
```

mean?

Also what does `__attribute__ ((__packed__));` mean here?

```
enum DeviceClass {
 DeviceClassInInterface = 0x00,
 DeviceClassCommunications = 0x2,
 DeviceClassHub = 0x9,
 DeviceClassDiagnostic = 0xdc,
 DeviceClassMiscellaneous = 0xef,
 DeviceClassVendorSpecific = 0xff,
 };
struct UsbDeviceDescriptor {
    u8 DescriptorLength; // +0x0                                                                                                                                           
    enum DescriptorType DescriptorType : 8; // +0x1                                                                                                                        
    u16 UsbVersion; // (in BCD 0x210 = USB2.10) +0x2                                                                                                                       
    enum DeviceClass Class : 8; // +0x4                                                                                                                                    
    u8 SubClass; // +0x5                                                                                                                                                   
    u8 Protocol; // +0x6                                                                                                                                                   
    u8 MaxPacketSize0; // +0x7                                                                                                                                             
    u16 VendorId; // +0x8                                                                                                                                                  
    u16 ProductId; // +0xa                                                                                                                                                 
    u16 Version; // +0xc                                                                                                                                                   
    u8 Manufacturer; // +0xe                                                                                                                                               
    u8 Product; // +0xf                                                                                                                                                    
    u8 SerialNumber; // +0x10                                                                                                                                              
    u8 ConfigurationCount; // +0x11                                                                                                                                        
 } __attribute__ ((__packed__));
```

Comment: also, what does the __attribute__ ((__packed__)); mean in here? why does it use __attrubute__((__packed__))?                                                                                                                struct UsbInterfaceDescriptor {
                InterfaceClassVendorSpecific = 0xff,
        } Class : 8; // +x05                                                                                                                                                   
        u8 SubClass;
        u8 Protocol;
        u8 StringIndex;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));

Comment: Please use the `edit` link below your question to edit it. And remember, one question per question.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you take some steps back, get a couple of beginners books, and start reading about structures and *bitfields*.

Comment: `__attribute__((__packed__))` is used to prevent the compiler from inserting meaningless bits in your struct to dictate alignment.

Comment: It's non-standard gibberish. Most likely it will not do what the programmer intended. The attribute suggests gcc, yet gcc will not pad bits across different types. Your best bet is to rewrite this whole code. Switch to `stdint.h` too while you are at it.

Comment: what does the added OtgControl mean? It means the name of the struct?              } __attribute__ ((__packed__)) OtgControl; // +0x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum DescriptorType DescriptorType : 8;
```

This is a **bitfield** of 8 bits. This indicates that 8 bits of the enum are included in the structure.

An `enum` variable in C has an implentation defined size (Ref 6.2.2.2 in C99 standard) . If you do not include this as a bitfield, you may use more than 8 bits to store this value.

```
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));
```

This indicates that the compiler should not add any **padding bytes** in between the struct elements. Usually, padding bytes are added between different struct elements to allow for easier aligned accesss of 32 bit or 16 bit types.

You can do a `sizeof (struct UsbDeviceDescriptor)` with and without the `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` and can see the difference.

This is a GCC specific extension. It is copied by some other compilers also, but by no means is portable code.

Comment: Enum bit-fields are also compiler specific. The standard only requires `int`, `unsigned int`, and `_Bool` to work in a bit-field.

Comment: Thanks Raje! So does it mean that every items on the device is 8 bits?  DeviceClassCommunications = 0x2, it will be saved as DeviceClassCommunications = 0x02?
 DeviceClass {
 DeviceClassInInterface = 0x00,
 DeviceClassCommunications = 0x2,
 DeviceClassHub = 0x9,
 DeviceClassDiagnostic = 0xdc,
 DeviceClassMiscellaneous = 0xef,
 DeviceClassVendorSpecific = 0xff,
 };

Comment: "An enum in C is the same type as an int" No. An enumerated variable has an implementation-defined size. Not to be confused with enumeration constants which are always `int`.

Comment: @BrianLee - There are some 16 bit values also. e.g.`ProductId` `VendorId`